# Eclipse Windows builder error

Tags: java

I am using Eclipse Kepler 4.3...I had to use GUI and so I downloaded Windows builder after which Eclipse started not responding every time I tried to do something. So I deleted Eclipse and removed the downloaded Windows builder components. And then again re-opened eclipse. Now there's a cross mark against every project and nothing compiles. It says error in the project. What do I do? Thank you. Cheers.

Comment: _It says error in the project_ what are those errors? have you tried adding required libraries to project? did you try giving clean build?

Comment: This can be many thing. Keeping Eclipe clean: http://wenku.baidu.com/view/5a06b3280066f5335a8121e0.html (sorry, the http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61566.html link doesn't seem to work now). The worst case: recreate the project.

Comment: The clean build worked. Thank you Pradeep Simha. Cheers.